# Android App is not properly resumed on Settings and About

Tags: bug, android-app

1. Navigate to *Settings* or *About* (previously: *Help*)
2. Pause the app, e.g. by pressing the device's home button
3. Navigate back to the app, e.g. by pressing the device's recents button
4. The app shows the last visited top level screen instead of Settings or About

This behavior is particularly confusing when tapping a link in the help screen and pressing the back button.

Android 4.4, version <s>0.1.70</s> 1.0.83

Comment: Repro'd partially on v1.0.83: the About page still behaves like this, but the Settings have been fixed.